# Does jqgrid display special characters?

Tags: jqgrid

I m trying to display the product list in the jqgrid but the product names are somewhat big and have special characters in them.And the data is not displayed I tried doing everything.

Earlier it was showing when there were simple product names.
Now it is not showing.Is the special character a problem.

Eg : Product name is : SONOMA life + style® Fern Leaf & Bamboo-Scented 4" x 4" Pillar Candle

Thanks
Riti

Comment: Try without special characters. Does it work? Good. Now add aspecial character. Does it work? You got your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider to use `autoencode:true` option of jqGrid. Per default the input data are interpret as HTML data and can contain HTML markup. If you want to display any text data the `autoencode:true` option can help you to display all the data like it be.

Moreover you should not forget to use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

on you page, save the HTML page in UTF-8 format and send the JSON/XML data from the server also always in UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to `utf8_encode("string")` your string in PHP.

Comment: You should accept answers if you want to gain reputation. I also only heard about this recently. Just click the green check for the answer you like.

Answer (score 0):

Recently ran upon the same problem.

The encoding of the HTTP header and the byte-order mark of your html file might also matter. There is a guy with a similar problem here - http://codemerx.com/jqgrid/forum/jqgrid-standalone/2-special-characters-in-jqgrid

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged here on SO. Please consider [editing your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186599) and adding a synopsis here.