# jqgrid doesnot display special symbols

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need jqgrid to display some special characters like "`<test>`" in some of the columns, tried using `autoencode=true` but it changed all the column to HTML encoding, like I had buttons in some other columns which don't need encoding, can we set autoencode for specific columns? Any ideas?

Edit: I have used the formatter as proposed by oleg,but I ran into issue where I had buttons in cols, where i need to toggle between edit mode to 'save',save and finished' and 'cancel'  i am posting the code but I am not sure on how to toggle between hide/unhide the buttons in Edit mode:

Grid Setup:

```
            $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("JSONData","CompanyInfo")%>',
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Company', 'Address' , 'Employers ', ''],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', align: 'left', sortable: false, editable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Company', index: 'Company', align: 'left', sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: ConvertLineChartoBR },
                { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', editoptions: { size: 100 }, align: 'left', sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', formatter: ConvertLineChartoBR, unformat: ConvertLineChartoN }, 
                { name: 'Employers', index: 'Employers', editoptions: { size: 100 }, align: 'left', sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea' },
                { name: 'act', index: 'act', editable: false, sortable: false, fixed: true, formatter: setupEdit}],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            rowNum: currRecords,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            recordtext: "View Records {0} - {1} of {2}",
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: 'Test'
        });
```

SetupEdit(For formatter)

```
      function setupEdit(cellvalue,options,rowObject) {

      var btnSave = "<input type='button' value='Save' style='display:none' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', '" + options.rowId + "', null,  '<%= Url.Action("GridSave","Company")%>', null, aftersavefunc);\" />";
      var btnSaveFinished = "<input type='button' value='Save & Finish' style='display:none' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('saveRow', '" + options.rowId + "', null, '<%= Url.Action("GridSaveFinished","Company")%>', null, aftersavefunc);\" />";
      var btnCancel = "<input type='button' value='Cancel' style='display:none' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', '" + options.rowId + "', aftercancelfunc);\" />";
      var Edit =  "<input type='button' value='Edit' class='editButton' onclick=\"$('#list').jqGrid('editRow','" + options.rowId+ "',false,oneditfunc);\" />";
        return btnSave + btnSaveFinished + btnCancel + Edit;
    }
```

OnEdit(On Edit button click)

```
 function oneditfunc(result, x) {
  // I need to unhide the button of the last column where buttons are populated in setupEdit
  // On Edit click, i need to enable btnSave,btnSaveFinished and btnCancel
  //Again on aftersavefunc/aftercancelfunc i need to reset back the column value to display on Edit button
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set `autoencode: true` only for one column.

I think that your real problem come because you place the HTML markup in the wrong way in the column where you create buttons. Probably you place the HTML markup as the part of data, which is not good. The better way is to use [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter). In the case you should place in JSON input for the button column only the *data* which can be used by formater for example as the text of the buttons. If you need the same text for buttons you can have empty data for the button column. For example

```
formatter: function () {
    return "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plus'></span>";
}
```

In the case you can use `autoencode: true` without any problems. The buttons will be displayed as needed and the texts like `<test>` will be encoded and correctly displayed.

**UPDATED**: You can use `getColumnIndexByName` which I used in many my old answers:

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
        var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                return i; // return the index
            }
        }
        return -1;
    };
```

It helps you to get the index of column in the `colModel` by the column. For example to make the buttons looks corresponds to the jQuery UI style you can use

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var iAct = getColumnIndexByName ($(this), 'act');
    $(this).find("tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iAct + 1) +
        ")>input[type='button']").button();
}
```

Let us you know the rowid and want to get the buttons which you placed in the column 'act'. Then you need to show some from there or hide other. You can use the following code fragment:

```
var iAct = getColumnIndexByName ($(this), 'act'),
    $td = $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(rowid) + ">td:nth-child(" + (iAct + 1) + ")"),
    $save = $td.find(">input[value='Save']"),
    $saveAndFinish = $td.find(">input[value='Save & Finish']"),
    $cancel = $td.find(">input[value='Cancel']"),
    $edit = $td.find(">input[value='Edit']");
$save.show();
$saveAndFinish.show();
$cancel.show();
$edit.hide();
```

I would recommend you to use icons with tooltips instead of texts in the buttons to save place in the grid.

Comment: thanks. I could set it up this way with no issues. However in edit mode, the edit button needs to be replaced with save and cancel buttons. I did that using setRowData. Now it looks like I can't use it anymore. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: @remo Why you don't use the predefined `formatter: 'actions'`? It do what you need. If you do need implement the same yourself you can add many buttons in the formatter, but some from there should be hidden: "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plus'></span>"<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-disk' style='display:none'></span>" then you can show the buttons which you need to display and hide unneeded buttons. The same do `formatter: 'actions'`.

Comment: I can't use predefined actions as I have more buttons to add in edit mode. I will try doing multiple buttons some in displayed and others hidden. Thanks

Comment: How can I unhide and hide the button when toggling? Can I access the value of object ?, it looks like I can't set setRowData in OnEditFunc

Comment: @remo: It's depend on the implementation. You should post the code which you use.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update, also It looks like $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid") is setting autoencode to false, is that right? I do that on the save

Comment: @remo: No, `reloadGrid` don't change the value of `autoencode` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML entities `&gt;` and `&lt;` for `>` and `<`, respectively.

I'm using them below:

> <test>

Another character that might help is `&amp;` for `&`.

Answer (score 0):

there being interpretted as html tags. you just need to change `< and >` to `&lt; and &gt;` .. if you use php, htmlspecialchars function will help you do this. But there are similar functions in most languages i believe.

Answer (score 0):

[Does jqgrid display special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512954/does-jqgrid-display-special-characters)

"You also have to utf8_encode("string") your string in PHP."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Please post possible duplicates in comments, i.e. "Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5512954/900747" (hit share on the question to get a link). Thank you!