# onclick event not fired on the button which is added to each subgrid cell of jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have added a button to each row of the subgrid of a jqGrid. I just followed the documentation of inline_editing for this.

I want to call the server side code on click of the button. But when I see the firebug it shows no request been made (not showing any url request)  on click of the button.

Below is my code,

```js
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgrid_id, row_id) {
 var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
 subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
 pager_id = "p_" + subgrid_table_id;
 $("#" + subgrid_id)
     .html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table><div id='" + pager_id + "' class='scroll'></div>");
 $mysubgrid = jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id);
 $mysubgrid.jqGrid({
     url: "serversub.php",
     datatype: "json",
     colNames: ['Product Id', 'Product Name', 'status', ''],
     width: 700,
     colModel: [{
         name: 'productid',
         index: 'productid',
         width: 55
     }, {
         name: 'productname',
         index: 'productname',
         width: 90
     }, {
         name: 'status',
         index: 'status',
         width: 80,
         search: false
     }, {
         name: 'link',
         index: 'link',
         width: 80,
         search: false
     }],
     rowNum: 20,
     sortname: 'num',
     sortorder: "asc",
     gridComplete: function () {
         var ids = $mysubgrid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
             var cl = ids[i];

           se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;'
  type='button' value='Update' onclick=\"$mysubgrid.saveRow('" + cl + "');\" />";
             $mysubgrid.jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                 link: se
             });
         }
     },
     editurl: "saveserversub.php"
 });
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function which you call in `onclick` have contains only **global** variables. You can't use local `$mysubgrid` variable.

I would recommend you to create buttons which you need inside of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) and to use (like in all other your grids) the option `gridview: true`. It will improve performance of the grid.

Additionally I think that you don't need to set any `onclick` on the buttons which you insert in the grid column. If the `click` event is fire and there are no event handler for the `click` the [bubbling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow) take place. So you can just use `onCellSelect` callback. If you need have the original DOM object of the clicked button you find it in `e.target`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I added the button using the custom formatter. You are correct that no need to write the click as the event bubbling takes place but I don't want the code in the callback function happen all the time.It should only happen on button click event. Of course I have written the callback onCellSelect but the event bubbling is not happening anyways ( I am not sure why?). Then how to get the rowid in the button click event?

Comment: @poddroid: Of you want to bind `click` events for all buttons of the grid body you can use just `$(this).find("input").click(yourEventHandler);` inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete`. If you have many other buttons in the grid and nee to bind only specific buttons see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9153396/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9085974/315935) how to find the pecific buttons. I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305904/315935) about usage of `onCellSelect`.